MapProxy and Mapnik missing layers for some tiles only
I'm using MapProxy to serve OSM tiles rendered by Mapnik and displaying them using OpenLayers; in general it seems to be working but the problem is that at all zoom levels some of the tiles seem to be missing layers. There are no errors reported in the MapProxy logs so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is going on.
Any ideas for debugging the root cause of this issue?

This is my mapproxy.yaml configuration.
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'sw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: mapnik
    title: Mapnik map
    sources: [mapnik_cache]

caches:
  mapnik_cache:
    grids: [bng]
    sources: [mapnik_source]

sources:
  mapnik_source:
    type: mapnik
    mapfile: /data/style/mapnik.xml
    #layers: mapnik
    #transparent: true

grids:
  bng:
    srs: EPSG:27700
    #bbox: [0, 0, 700000, 1300000]
    bbox: [-238375.0, 0.0, 900000.0, 1376256.0]
    bbox_srs: EPSG:27700
    origin: 'sw'

